# How do these vars get initialised?

Tags: actionscript, red5

The following code is a combination of samples taken from red5.  Basically I am trying to combine a live stream subscriber with a chat box based on shared objects.  I'm not a flash developer and have a very limited understanding of what is going on here.

```
// ** AUTO-UI IMPORT STATEMENTS **
import org.red5.utils.Connector;
import org.red5.samples.simplechat.BasicChat;
// ** END AUTO-UI IMPORT STATEMENTS **
import com.neoarchaic.ui.Tooltip;
import org.red5.net.Stream;
//import org.red5.utils.Delegate;
import com.blitzagency.xray.util.XrayLoader;

class org.red5.samples.livestream.subscriber.Main extends MovieClip {
// Constants:
    public static var CLASS_REF = org.red5.samples.livestream.subscriber.Main;
    public static var LINKAGE_ID:String =     "org.red5.samples.livestream.subscriber.Main";
// Public Properties:
// Private Properties:
private var stream:Stream;
private var cam:Camera;
// UI Elements:

// ** AUTO-UI ELEMENTS **
    private var connector:Connector;
    private var publish_video:Video;
    private var chat:BasicChat;
// ** END AUTO-UI ELEMENTS **
    private var uri:String = "rtmpt://localhost/oflaDemo";

// Initialization:
    private function Main() {XrayLoader.loadConnector("xray.swf");}
    private function onLoad():Void { configUI(); }

// Public Methods:
// Semi-Private Methods:
// Private Methods:
    private function configUI():Void 
    {
        // setup the tooltip defaults
    Tooltip.options = {size:10, font:"_sans", corner:0};
    // setup cam
    cam = Camera.get();
    // get notified of connection changes
    connector.addEventListener("connectionChange", this);

    // set the uri
    Connector.red5URI = uri;

    // initialize the connector
    connector.configUI();
    connector.makeConnection();
}

private function connectionChange(evtObj:Object):Void
{       

    if(evtObj.connected) 
    {
        // setup stream
        // XXX: odd hack needed for flashIDE.
        var conn = evtObj.connection; 
        var x = new Stream(conn);
        stream = x;
        stream.play("red5StreamDemo", -1);
        publish_video.attachVideo(stream);
        trace(chat);
        // register the NetConnection that GlobalObject will need
        chat.registerConnection(conn);

        // connect the shared object
        chat.connectSO();
    }
}

}
```

I don't think that `var chat` is being initialized anywhere as `trace(chat)` prints 'undefined'.  However `var connector` and `var publish_video` seem to collect their instances from the stage.

This sample code included those two and worked fine, but I can't make my additions behave the same way.

I have added an instance of BasicChat to the stage (I'm using Flash CS4) and have spent the past many hours playing with it's various properties, layers and groupings, but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest why my `var chat` isn't collecting its instance from the stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the instance name of your BasicChat stage instance? It should be set to "chat". To set it, click the stage instance and find the instance name field in the Properties panel (first/top visible field).